# How to highlight consecutive cells that match specific criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I've got a column of randomly sorted numbers (10,20,30,40,50,60) and want to highlight the cells that only have 20-10 consecutively.  I tried creating another column and using =OR(AND(C2=20,C3=10)) to see if the cells met that criteria and it worked but I need them highlighted, as I will be highlighting different combinations of numbers in different colors.  I tried conditional formatting>new formula and this did not work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first time 20 appears is C2 and the first time 10 appears it C3.  I started highlighting cells (pressed <kbd>Crtl</kbd> before selecting cells) from C2 to the end. I used conditional formatting `->` new formula and entered:

```
=AND(C2=20,C3=10)
```

This only highlighted cells every time 20 appeared.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I wanted both cells to be highlighted rather than being told if the 20 in one cell and 10 immediately following in the next cell condition is met.